# bootstrap columns from reflowing hack (to create netflix like horizontal slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to recreate the netflix horizontal slider/carousel with bootstrap and css like this: http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Netflix-My-List-web-screenshot-002.jpg

I haven't set up the css transitions/animations but i have gotten elements to repeat without reflowing using a width hack. I plan on using javascript to repeat the elements and  to make the width of the container only as wide as the inner elements. This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/7541/

html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 hero-unit">
        <h1>Bootstrap jsFiddle Skeleton</h1>
        <p>Fork this fiddle to test your Bootstrap stuff.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hero-unit col-xs-2">
        <h1>Bootstrap jsFiddle Skeleton</h1>
        <p>Fork this fiddle to test your Bootstrap stuff.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hero-unit col-xs-2">
        <h1>Bootstrap jsFiddle Skeleton</h1>
        <p>Fork this fiddle to test your Bootstrap stuff.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hero-unit col-xs-2">
        <h1>Bootstrap jsFiddle Skeleton</h1>
        <p>Fork this fiddle to test your Bootstrap stuff.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hero-unit col-xs-2">
        <h1>Bootstrap jsFiddle Skeleton</h1>
        <p>Fork this fiddle to test your Bootstrap stuff.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hero-unit col-xs-2">
        <h1>Bootstrap jsFiddle Skeleton</h1>
        <p>Fork this fiddle to test your Bootstrap stuff.</p>
    </div>    
</div>
</diV>
```

css

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.container{
    height: 150px;
    background: grey;
    width: 500%
}
.hero-unit {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:red;
    height: 100px;
}
```

is this a super jank method? I'm not very experienced in web development.